# SQL query with deeper relationship

Tags: mysql, sql

```
Table: user
Columns
- id
- username
- full_name

Table: pet
Columns
- id
- pet_name
- color_id

Table: pet_color
Columns
- id
- color

Table: results
Columns
- id
- user_id_1
- user_id_2
- user_id_3
- pet_id
- date
- some_text
```

This:

```
SELECT A.id, B.full_name, C.full_name, D.full_name, E.pet_name, A.date, A.some_text
FROM RESULTS AS A 
LEFT OUTER JOIN USER AS B ON A.USER_ID1 = B.ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN USER AS C ON A.USER_ID2 = C.ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN USER AS D ON A.USER_ID3 = D.ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN PET AS E ON A.PET_ID = E.ID
```

will give me almost everything that I want except 'pet_color.color', but I can not figure it out what should I add to the query to get that too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT A.id, B.full_name, C.full_name, D.full_name, E.pet_name, A.date, A.some_text, pc.color
FROM RESULTS AS A 
LEFT OUTER JOIN USER AS B ON A.USER_ID1 = B.ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN USER AS C ON A.USER_ID2 = C.ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN USER AS D ON A.USER_ID3 = D.ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN PET AS E ON A.PET_ID = E.ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN PET_COLOR PC on E.color_id = pc.id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT A.id, B.full_name, C.full_name, D.full_name, E.pet_name, A.date, A.some_text, PC.color
FROM RESULTS AS A 
LEFT OUTER JOIN USER AS B ON A.USER_ID1 = B.ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN USER AS C ON A.USER_ID2 = C.ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN USER AS D ON A.USER_ID3 = D.ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN PET AS E ON A.PET_ID = E.ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN PET_COLOR PC ON E.COLOR_ID = PC.ID
```

Answer (score 0):

Not tried, but this should work

```
SELECT A.id, B.full_name, C.full_name, D.full_name, E.pet_name, A.date, A.some_text
FROM RESULTS AS A 
LEFT OUTER JOIN USER AS B ON A.USER_ID1 = B.ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN USER AS C ON A.USER_ID2 = C.ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN USER AS D ON A.USER_ID3 = D.ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN PET AS E ON A.PET_ID = E.ID
INNER JOIN PET_COLOR PC ON PC.ID = E.COLOR_ID
```